# Playing MediaPlayer from String

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Have no clue why this won't work....

```
String pSound = "R.raw.sound";
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, pSound);
mp.start();
```

Do I have to parse somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a resource id-integer, not a String:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
```

Comment: I'm receiving the String from a bundle form another Acitivity... How cna I bunlde the resID Int???

Comment: If it's in the same application, you can just add the resource id to your bundle with putInt().

Comment: So I get the ID with this:

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("sound", "raw", getPackageName());

And the putInt(resID) in the bundle?